# rollback failed for rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-migrations

I made a mistake in editing a rails migration (I'm using rails 3.1.0rc5).  So I corrected it and attempted to do a `rake db:rollback` followed by a `rake db:migrate db:test:prepare`.  But the rollback failed for some reason.  Here's the rollback portion of the migration:

```
  def down
    drop_table :assets
  end
```

this is the response from `db:rollback`:

```
==  CreateAssets: reverting ===================================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration

Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

so I just manually deleted the assets table in the database (I'm just using the sqlite3 dbs), commented out the `drop_table :assets` line and ran `db:rollback` again:

```
==  CreateAssets: reverting ===================================================
-- drop_table("assets")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: assets: DROP TABLE "assets"

Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Why is it trying to drop the assets table?  I commented out (and actually later deleted) that `drop_table :assets` line from the migration.  I even did a `grep -r assets` to see where rails might be getting that drop command from, but couldn't find anything.

So my question is how do I get this migration re-run?  And I'm curious where rails is getting that drop command?

***UPDATE***: It turns out that rails 3.1 actually doesn't look at the migration class' `down` method when rolling back!  It looks at the `change` method's migration commands and reverses them.  That's why `rake db:rollback` was trying to drop the assets table even after I removed the `drop_table :assets` instruction!  How I fixed this is I changed the `change` method to the old rails 3.0 style `up` method.  Then rails looked at the `down` method which I had removed the `drop_table` command from and the rollback was successful.

Comment: Had a similar situation (Rails 3.2), and replacing 'change' with 'up' worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations changed a fair bit with the latest rails, especially reversing migrations.
I think http://shardul.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/reversible-migrations/ will provide you with the info and options you need.

btw I had a lot of issues with the 3.1. rc candidates (e.g. rc4, rc5) and have had to stay at 3.0.9 for stable new apps right now.

Comment: That edgerails article solved it for me!  I'll update my question with the result.